# get occurence of multiple rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm

I have a table that contains students publications like this

| id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | anthony |
| 3 | steven |
| 4 | lucille |
| 5 | anthony |
| 6 | steven |
| 7 | john |
| 8 | lucille |
| 9 | john |
| 10 | anthony |
| 11 | steven |
| 12 | lucille |
| 13 | john |

so the idea is about to have a query that fetchs all ordered occurences of a determinated student names

**context :**

answer to the question : how many times John is publishing just after Anthony (who is publishing just after Steven ...) and get id of each occurence

**example :**

If I look for all occurences of `[john, anthony]` I'll get (note that the ids must be successive for each occurence)

| id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | anthony |
| 9 | john |
| 10 | anthony |

Or :

| id | -- comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (id of first occurence of john, anthony) |
| 9 | (id of second occurence of john, anthony) |

If I look for `[anthony, steven, lucille]` i'll get

| id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | anthony |
| 3 | steven |
| 4 | lucille |
| 10 | anthony |
| 11 | steven |
| 12 | lucille |

Or :

| id | -- comment |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | (id of first occurence of anthony, steven, lucille) |
| 10 | (id of second occurence of anthony, steven, lucille) |

Any ideas or leads to help me move forward?

Comment: When you query for `john, anthony` do you expect that order or would `anthony, john` also be acceptable?

Comment: just `john, anthony`

Comment: The question is not well defined. **(1)** Can a name appear more than once in your search list?. **(2)** Are ids always successive? please note there are no gaps at all between the min id (1) and the max id (13).  **(3)** If gaps are possible, so when you are looking for successive names, are you looking for successive numbers or successive rows? **(4)** Please give some context. Is it work related? homework? what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: In addition: **(5)** What is the expected number of rows? **(6)** Are there additional columns that need to be displayed? **(7)** Is this dataset is actually a subset of a larger dataset divided somehow to subsets?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz (1) yes, (2) there is no gaps, (4) this is a research project, we are trying to get occurences of students publications in the order, for example we look for how many times John and Anthony are publishing one before the other (in order), (5) i've added some examples

Comment: **(1)** just to make sure - I'm referring not the table with the data but to what you are searching for, e.g., `[john, anthony, john, john, anthony]` **(5)** The size (in number of rows) of your real data set

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, yes it can appears more than once, or you can show a table like in the second example [1, 9] (just ids)
(5) for the size expected, i'm open to two solutions : 1. a list of occurence data like [john, anthony, john, anthoy] or [1, 9], in the first example i'll divise the number of rows by the the number of my first array to have the correct occurence number, and in the second one i'll just count rows to have occurences

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I also added a context in the publication, to be more clear (i think i didn't answer well to question 5; we have a database with millions rows)

Comment: We're good with **(5)** - so 1M records it is. As for **(1)** it seems you still don't get my intension - I'm not asking about the dataset, nor the result set - I'm asking about the search sequence. You gave an example where you search for `[john, anthony]` and i'm asking if `[john, anthony, john]`  is also a legitimate search (it seems to make things significantly more complicated)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz ah ok i understand the question, Yes we can have [john, anthony, john, john, john] as expected entries too, of [john, john, john], there is no limitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick, performance wise.

The main idea is to split the data by the first student that is in our search list, but not in all places -
Since the same student can appear multiple times in our search list, we need to make sure that we're not breaking the pattern in the middle.
We're doing that by verifying that each occurrence of the first student is far enough from its previous occurrence, that is, the distance between the two occurrences is bigger than the search list length (the number of non-unique students' names within the search list)

```
with
 prm(students) as (select 'anthony,steven,lucille,anthony')
,prm_ext(search_pattern, first_student, tokens_num) as 
 (
    select  regexp_replace(students, '^|(,)','\1\d+;', 'g') as search_pattern
           ,split_part(students, ',', 1)                    as first_student
           ,array_length(string_to_array(students, ','), 1) as tokens_num
           
    from    prm
)
,prev_student as
(
    select  id
           ,student
           ,lag(id) over (partition by student order by id) as student_prev_id
    
    from    t
)
,seq as
(
    select  id
           ,student
           ,sum(case when student = p.first_student and coalesce(id - student_prev_id >= p.tokens_num, true) then 1 end) over (order by id) as seq_id
           ,id - max(case when student = p.first_student then id end) over (order by id) as distance_from_first_student
    
    from    prev_student cross join prm_ext as p
    
    order by id
)
select    split_part(unnest(regexp_matches(string_agg(id || ';' || student, ',' order by id), (select search_pattern from prm_ext), 'g')), ';', 1)::int  as id
     
from      seq cross join prm_ext p

where     seq_id is not null
     and  distance_from_first_student < p.tokens_num
     
group by  seq_id
```

This is the result for an extended data sample:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 16 |
| 22 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5933857ff956730177e10d80b42b6ad7)

Comment: See updated answer. Add some rows to data sample, to demonstrate the complexity.

Comment: This was really fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start with this and if it explodes we'll do some performance improvements, with the price of making the code a little bit more complicated.

```
with
 prm(students) as (select 'anthony,steven,lucille')
,prm_ext(students_regex) as (select regexp_replace(students, '^|(,)','\1\d+;', 'g') from prm)
select  split_part(unnest(regexp_matches(string_agg(id || ';' || student, ',' order by id), (select students_regex from prm_ext), 'g')), ';', 1)::int  as id
from    t
```

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 10 |

```
with
 prm(students) as (select 'anthony,steven,lucille')
,prm_ext(students_regex) as (select regexp_replace(students, '^|(,)','\1\d+;', 'g') from prm)
select  cols[1]::int   as id
       ,cols[2]::text  as student
       
from   (select  string_to_array(string_to_table(unnest(regexp_matches(string_agg(id || ';' || student, ',' order by id), (select students_regex from prm_ext), 'g')), ','), ';') as cols
        from    t
       ) t
```

| id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | anthony |
| 3 | steven |
| 4 | lucille |
| 10 | anthony |
| 11 | steven |
| 12 | lucille |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=131cde06c7a9a29b0edf7bee30c8d5f6)

Comment: this is awsome ! it works fine, but got ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1451987632 with our real database, i'll accept the answer, but if you can improve performance, it will be better. i'm more interested in the first solution, with just ids, so no need to improve both of them